# How can I solve this linear partial differential equation of 2 variables with Fourier transform?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, linear-pde

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ solve using Fourier transform

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-\gamma u,$$

where $k, \gamma$ are positive constants and $u(x,t)|_{t=0}=f(x).$

First generally (the result should be in a form of convolution integral), then explicitly with $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Fourier transform, but I didn't manage to make it to the step with convolution integral.

Comment: Please include your work in the question.

Comment: Through multiplication by a certain function you can get back to the heat equation : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1278905).